# How can I search for a keyword in all public LinkedIn data?

Tags: ruby, linkedin-api

I'm using the `linkedin` gem. I want to search for a keyword in all the public data available on LinkedIn. For example, if I search for a keyword like "microsoft", it would search for "microsoft" in LinkedIn people, jobs, companies, connections, groups, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Via the [LinkedIn public APIs](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis) you could perform separate searches that would accomplish most of what you need, then could combine the returned data as needed.

Search all LinkedIn user's for "Microsoft" via the People Search API:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api

Search all jobs via the Jobs Search API:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/job-search-api

Search all companies via the Company Search API:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/company-search

There is no groups search at this time, so that would not be possible.